# Notification bar getting black when showing SnackBar

Tags: android

I'm using SnackBar in my android lolypop app. Every thing going fine but when SnackBar is open, notification Bar gets black, and when SnackBar close again notification bar looks fine as defines.
Here is code:

```
    SnackBar snackbar = new SnackBar(ActivityName.this,
            "msg", "OK",
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                }
            });
    snackbar.show();
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: how you get the context ?

Comment: using ActivityName.this

Comment: Snack**B**ar or Snackbar? I can see only [Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html)

Comment: R u mad? U r not able to see attached code. #Rahul Tiwari